# Notification actions text colors on Android

Tags: android, text, colors, notifications, action

In Android, I have added two actions to a notification.
Now I want to set different colors for each text action.

for exemple:

```
builder.addAction(R.drawable.action1_icon,"action1",action1Intent);
builder.addAction(R.drawable.action2_icon,"action2",action2Intent);

"action1" in green color   
"action2" in red color
```

how can i do this?

Thanks.

Comment: did u get a solution ?